# Emacs powerline not displaying arrow

Tags: emacs, powerline

I am trying to configure emacs `powerline`, after trying multiple times, i still can't get it working correctly as shown in the figure below.

[image]

It seems to me that some font is missing in my system, but i don't know which one. I am using Mac El Capitan, the emacs version is 24.5.1.

Comment: Can you evaluate `(image-type-available-p 'xpm)` ? It is most likely your emacs build is missing `xpm` image support.

Comment: Try patch font see if it helps

Comment: Can you try to evaluate ``powerline-default-separator`` value ?

Comment: Questions about *using* programs such as Emacs are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they are specific to programming modes; you may be able to get help on [emacs.se] or [su].  If your question is about programming Emacs, then please [edit] to include a [mcve] of the Lisp or C code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use following command

```
# clone
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
# install
cd fonts
./install.sh
# clean-up a bit
cd ..
rm -rf fonts
```

You may need to manually select your favorite powerline font

picture -> [select your favorite powerline font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5stE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing these settings:

```lisp
(setq powerline-arrow-shape 'curve)
(setq powerline-default-separator-dir '(right . left))
 '(right . left))
```